# How do I use routes for multi-tenancy in all but one controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Our app has multiple tenants. Every tenant has a short code assigned to them that users know them by. I want to use that code in my URLs as a route parameter, and have Ninject inject a DbContext with the tenant's database connection string into the tenant-specific controllers.

So for examine I have a CarController, and every tenant has their own products. The URLs would look like {tenantcode}/{controller}/{action}. I understand how to do this part.

However, I have several controllers that should NOT be instanced by tenant. Specifically, the home controller, and account controller for login/registration. These don't matter.

So example URLs I need:

- myapp.com/ - HomeController
- myapp.com/Account/Login - AccountController
- myapp.com/GM/Car/Add - CarController that has GM's DbContext injected
- myapp.com/Ford/Car/Add - CarController that has Ford's DbContext injected

How can I exclude certain controllers from routes? Running ASP.NET MVC 5.

---

Many thanks to Darko Z for starting me in the right direction. I ended up using a hybrid of traditional routes, and the new attribute based routing in MVC 5.

First, the "excluded" routes got decorated with the new RouteAttribute class

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly TenantContext context;

    public HomeController(TenantContext Context)
    {
        this.context = Context;
    }

    //
    // GET: http://myapp.com/
    // By decorating just this action with an empty RouteAttribute, we make it the "start page"
    [Route]
    public ActionResult Index(bool Error = false)
    {
        // Look up and make a nice list of the tenants this user can access
        var tenantQuery =
            from u in context.Users
            where u.UserId == userId
            from t in u.Tenants
            select new
            {
                t.Id,
                t.Name,
            };

        return View(tenantQuery);
    }
}

// By decorating this whole controller with RouteAttribute, all /Account URLs wind up here
[Route("Account/{action}")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Account/LogOn
    public ActionResult LogOn()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/LogOn
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnViewModel model, string ReturnUrl)
    {
        // Log on logic here
    }
}
```

Next, I register the tenant generic route that Darko Z suggested. It's important to call MapMvcAttributeRoutes() before making other routes. This is because my attribute based routes are the "exceptions", and like he said, those exceptions have to be at the top to make sure they are picked up first.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        // exceptions are the attribute-based routes
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        // tenant code is the default route
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Tenant",
            url: "{tenantcode}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "TenantHome", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as I'm sure you know you specify routes in MVC in the order from most specific to most generic. So in your case I would do something like this:

```
//exclusions - basically hardcoded, pacing this at the top will 
//ensure that these will be picked up first. Of course this means 
//you must make sure that tenant codes cannot be the same as any 
//controller name here
routes.MapRoute(
    "Home",                                              
    "Home/{action}/{id}",                         
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" } 
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Account",                                              
    "Account/{action}/{id}",                         
    new { controller = "Account", action = "Index", id = "" } 
);

//tenant generic route
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",                                              
    "{tenantcode}/{controller}/{action}",                         
    new { tenantcode = "Default", controller = "Tenant", action = "Index" } 
);

//default route
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",                                              
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                         
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" } 
);
```

This is obviously only good if there are less excluded controllers than controllers that need the tenant code. If not then you can take the opposite approach and reverse the above. Main takeaway here is that (happy to be proven wrong) there is no way to have a generic ignore within an AddRoute call. While there is an IgnoreRoute, that just completely doesn't apply any routing rules and is used for static resources. Hope that helps.